# Using Glue Connections to connect Redshift Permission issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, aws-glue

I tried to use Glue databases connections to connect to Redshift. I set up vpc for glue to access to Redshift, following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-glue-access.html. Besides, I make sure my user name and password are correct by successfully using Workbench to access to the Redshift. Then, make sure the IAM role I am using is a Glue service rule with `AmazonS3FullAccess`, `AWSGlueServiceRole`, `AmazonRedshiftFullAccess`, `AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess` policies. Finally, I added `decrypt` policy to access KMS key associated to Redshift.

But I still got the permission error following. Not sure which step went wrong?

```
DataCatalog Connection issue : The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access. .
```